# Including association to active model serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activerecord, serialization

I have a problem with a multiple database queries in my index method of the controller. Basically, I'm rendering a JSON that is first serialized by ActiveModelSerializer see below:

```
def index
  packs = Pack.editable_by(current_user)
  render json: packs, each_serializer: PackSerializer, include: :documents, root: false
end
```

so, each of the pack from the packs array is serialized by it. The serializer itself depends on association (one pack can have many documents), thats why I added the `include: :documents` so that it is eager loaded and avoid N+1 query.

unfortunately it doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to avoid N+1 query in such case?

the  `PackSerializer` roughly looks like this:

```
class PackSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes #some attributes

  def doc_title
     @object.latest_document.title
  end

  ...

end




class Pack < ActiveRecord::Base

  ...

  def latest_document
    documents.where(is_published: true).order(:created_at).last
  end

  ...
end
```

Comment: Hey like the `latest_document` does another query, it is the different query I think, could you describe how do you describe the `latest_document` in your `Pack` model ?

Comment: `latest_document` is simply document that has the newest publication date. So it does and sql query from all the documents belonging to a pack and picks the one that has the newest publication date

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be enough to include `documents` in the query before, so

```
def index
  packs = Pack.editable_by(current_user).includes(:documents)
  render json: packs, each_serializer: PackSerializer, root: false
end
```

Comment: when I use `includes` there it doesn't solve the issue (still there are N+1 queries), it only adds one more query that retrieves the documents prior the serializing. I don't know why but somehow `PackSerializer` ignores this query and decides to do new ones each time it invokes `latest document`